# Add permissions base on roles of group in keycloak

Tags: mapping, keycloak, openid-connect, auth0

I first set my application base on **Auth0**, with roles and permissions setup. Result user are linked with x *roles*, and Auth0 inject to the token claim an array of linked *permissions*. Now my app need to become also compatible to use **KeyCloak**.

How to inject into the token the *permissions* array, like with Auth0?

Answer (score 1):

To match same beaver of Auth0, on keycloak all the auth0-roles are set as group. And all auth0-permission as roles.

Now to allow to inject into the token the related roles of *groups* linked with a user, I created a **Script Mapper** in the client like this:

```
var ArrayList = Java.type("java.util.ArrayList");
var permissions = new ArrayList();
user.getGroups().forEach(function(groupModel) {
    groupModel.getRoleMappings().forEach(function(roleModel) {
        var roleName = roleModel.getName();
        if(!permissions.contains(roleName)) {
            permissions.add(roleName);
        }
    });
});
token.setOtherClaims("permissions", permissions);
```

Take me time to find the best way to make it working. But if you know a better solution. Thank you for sharing ;-)